# Limit query time on Azure Synapse Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

On [Azure Synapse Analytics](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/synapse-analytics/), users can inadvertently run very resource-consuming queries over potentially large amounts of data.

On SQL Server, it's possible to configure a [server-wide remote query timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-remote-query-timeout-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver16&viewFallbackFrom=azure-sqldw-latest) to limit this. Ideally, a database will provide an option to do this on an ad-hoc basis (i.e. query by query).

Is this possible on Azure Synapse Analytics (pool and/or serverless).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is yes, it is possible to do it on Azure Syanapse Analytics. You can use a feature similar to Resource Governor on SQL Server called Work Load Management {1}. Using a `workload group`, you can set a parameter called `QUERY_EXECUTION_TIMEOUT_SEC` to define how long a query can run. Using the workload group you can define the parameter for a user, group of user, label, context, etc. {2}{3}. Please, take a look at the documentation below:

```
CREATE WORKLOAD GROUP group_name
 WITH
 (   MIN_PERCENTAGE_RESOURCE = value 
   , CAP_PERCENTAGE_RESOURCE = value 
   , REQUEST_MIN_RESOURCE_GRANT_PERCENT = value
  [ [ , ] REQUEST_MAX_RESOURCE_GRANT_PERCENT = value ]
  [ [ , ] IMPORTANCE = { LOW | BELOW_NORMAL | NORMAL | ABOVE_NORMAL | HIGH } ]
  [ [ , ] QUERY_EXECUTION_TIMEOUT_SEC = value ] )
  [ ; ]
```

{1}
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-workload-management

{2}
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-workload-classification

{3}
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-workload-group-transact-sql?toc=%2Fazure%2Fsynapse-analytics%2Fsql-data-warehouse%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fsynapse-analytics%2Fsql-data-warehouse%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-sqldw-latest&preserve-view=true

{4}
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-workload-isolation#execution-rules